# Using Set Notation, Find an Expression for at Least P Things in a Queue are Present.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Suppose a truck depot has two lines $A$ and $B$. let $A_i$ denote "there are at least $i$ trucks in $A$" and $B_i$ denote "there are at least $i$ objects in $B$."
>
> Find an expression using set notation for,
>
> "There are at least $3$ trucks in queue for the depot".

This is how I am reasoning the question

$A_0 = \{0, 1, 2, ... , i\}$ and $A_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\} \implies A_0\cap B_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$

$A_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$ and $A_3 = \{0, 1, 2, ... , i\} \implies A_3\cap B_0 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$

So I have the following so far,

$$(A_0\cap B_3) \cup (A_3\cap B_0)$$

But for $A_1$ and $B_2$ the intersection yields,

$A_1 = \{1, 2, 3, ... , i\}$ and $B_2 = \{2, 3, 4, ... , i\} \implies A_1\cap B_2 = \{2, 3, 4, ... , i\}$

The only way I can keep getting the set  $\{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$ is if I keep taking the intersection of $A_3$ (or $B_3$).

That is for example

$A_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$ and $B_2 = \{2, 3, 4, ... , i\} \implies A_3\cap B_2 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$

But since there is at least $3$ trucks in one line and $1$ in the other, there is at least $4$ trucks in line for the depot.

> How would you answer this question?

Comment: It looks as though you're looking for a *proposition* rather than a set...

Comment: So simply $A_2\cap B_1$, $A_1\cap B_2$, ... etc. would suffice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is how I am reasoning the question
>
> $A_0 = \{0, 1, 2, ... , i\}$ and $B_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\} \implies A_0\cap B_3 = \{3, 4, 5, ... , i\}$

No.

$A_i$ says "there are at least $i$ trucks in line A".   It is an event; you don't *need* to represent that as anything else; and certainly a set of integers wouldn't be appropriate.

$B_i$ says "there are at least $i$ trucks in line B".

You wish to say "there are at least $3$ trucks in lines A and B (in total)."  *This* is what you want to represent using set operations.

That is: $(A_0{\cap}B_3)~\cup~(A_1{\cap}B_2)~\cup~(A_2{\cap}B_1)~\cup~(A_3{\cap}B_0)$

---

Comment: So since we're talking 'in total', we're not concerned with which elements in A and B are shared in their intersection? i.e. just the least number of elements

Comment: So as Richard comments, I should think of it from more of a logic perspective? That is $\wedge$, meaning 'and'?

Comment: Oh wow, it completely passed me that it was an event. Thanks @Graham Kemp.

Comment: Think of them as events.  Their elements are outcomes, not the trucks themselves.  Their intersection are the set of shared outcomes.  Thus $A_1\cap B_2$ is the event that "line A has at least 1 truck and line B has at least 2 trucks".  @Ron.

Comment: Which can be simplified into $$B_3~\cup~(A_1{\cap}B_2)~\cup~(A_2{\cap}B_1)~\cup~A_3$$

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to think of $A_i$ and $B_i$ as a *predicates* or *propositional functions* that map non negative integer $i$ to *propositions* or statements about trucks in queues (and possibly to define the predicates to mean there are *exactly* $i$ trucks in queue A and B respectively).

Then, to state that there are at least 3 trucks waiting, we could simply assert something like $A_i \land B_j \land i+j \ge 3$. Notice that there are no sets involved in this interpretation.